# Perform Within transformation manually in R

Tags: r, panel-data, mass

I was recently working with the `rlm` function from the `MASS` package, seeking to fit a robust regression for a panel. Just like many other functions, `rlm` does not have a built-in way to introduce fixed effects. ID dummies however cost too much degrees of freedom and doesn't allow for two-way fixed effects.

This got me wondering whether there is a convenient way of "tricking" R into including individual or two-way fixed effects in a regression by performing the within transformation manually? I haven't seen anything about this flying around so possible I am getting the concept wrong. But out of interest: Has anyone done this before?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about fitting a statistical model to your data, you should ask for statistical advice at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. Rather than trying to trick an existing function, find a method that's appropriate for your data.

Comment: There does not seem to be a readily available function in R that allows for robust estimation with two-way fixed effects